# SQUISH issue to recognize "&" in GUI object names

Tags: object, properties, objectmapper, squish

I use SQUISH to perform automated tests (written in python) on a GUI application (based Linux SUSE 15) with Qt version 5.9.4.
This application contains objects with properties (example name of a menu) containing the character "&".

My test script crashes everytime an object containing the character "&" (in its properties) is called in the script.
The error is :
"LookupError: Object 'Hardwired links from RCSL to turbine I&C' not found

For debugging, I erase this character from the the application design ==> No more issues were observed, the test scripts passed.

But, it is not a sustainble solution, I need the "&" character in my application.

Do you guys have any information about SQUISH having problem with managing certain characters as "&" ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message may indicate a special case: Using the plain text of an object to look up the same.

Please do not use this undocumented (and generally unsupported) approach.

Instead, please record an interaction with the respective object, and then make use of the object name that Squish automatically generated for it.

Or [pick](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/picking-inspecting-objects/#how-to-pick-an-object) the object and [copy](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/picking-inspecting-objects/#copying-object-names) the object name.